# Postgresql nested select max(sum())

Tags: postgresql, nested, aggregate

My Query:

```
select table.attribute, count(table.attribute) AS cnt from table
group by table.attribute
order by cnt desc;
```

The output is something like:

```
 attribute | cnt 
-----------+-----
 A         |   2
 B         |   2
 G         |   1
 F         |   1
```

But i only want the max values (A & B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the power of [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to achieve this:

```
WITH count_values 
         AS (SELECT table.attribute, 
                    Count(table.attribute) AS cnt 
             FROM   table 
             GROUP  BY table.attribute), 
         max_values 
         AS (SELECT Max(cnt) AS max_cnt 
             FROM   (SELECT cnt 
                     FROM   count_values) sub) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM   count_values cv 
           JOIN max_values mv 
             ON mv.max_cnt = cv.cnt;
```

Comment: Cheers to you and @klin all the resources i found didnt worked for me!

Comment: Glad to help you @AnnoyedGuy

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single level of nesting:

```
select attribute, 
       cnt
from (
  select attribute, 
         count(*) AS cnt, 
         max(count(*)) over () as max_cnt
  from t
  group by attribute
) t
where cnt = max_cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use rank as below

```
with cte as (
    select *, Rank() over(order by cnt desc) as rnk from yourattribute
) select * from cte where rnk = 1
```